# Ethereum vs InterPlanetary

Tags: ipfs

I've been reading about Ethereum and it's fundamentals for a while now. 
I wonder what is difference between Ethereum and InterPlanetary File System ?

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms:
Ethereum is a blockchain based smart contract platform, while IPFS is a distributed, content-addressed file system.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System

https://www.ethereum.org/

https://ipfs.io

Answer (score 0):

<s>It's like Bitcoin and Bittorent.</s> One is blockchain, another is peer-to-peer file sharing distributed system.

*Ethereum* is like a foundation with it's own currency Ether<sup>1</sup>. Foundation gives you an ability to build your own decentralized applications using Smart Contracts. There is a myriad of use cases for it.

*Ipfs* in many cases is used alongside Ethereum because data storage is very expensive in blockchain, but storing hash (ipfs address) is much cheaper and ipfs file system is distributed.

---

*1. Developers and users can not only exchange this currency, but use it to pay for any computations which occur during interaction or deployment of Smart Contract.*

Answer (score 0):

They are totally different as they are trying to solve different problems.

But I'll try to explain it with an example. We want to make a NFT project.

What do we need?

- A place to run our small program (minting, transfer of NTFs etc., save ownership, link to NFT)
- A place to host our JPEGs (they are often too big to save on-chain)

1. One of the places where we can upload a small program is ethereum. Ethereum smart contracts are basically small programs that run on the ethereum virtual machine. Some variables in these contracts may include a url that is linked to IPFS where eg. a JPEG is hosted. So when you see this link eg. https://dweb.link/ipfs/bafybeigdyrzt5sfp7udm7hu76uh7y26nf3efuylqabf3oclgtqy55fbzdi it tells you that on this url something is waiting for you and it is saved on the IPFS network.
2. We need to have a place where we can store our JPEGs in a decentralised way. **IPFS** is a decentralised file system. It's like Amazon S3 but a decentralised version. It has some similarities to BitTorrent or other peer2peer networks. So when in our smart contract that lives on the ethereum chain links to a url that leads to IPFS goes to the `dweb.link` gateway. The gateway is like an entrance door to the peer-to-peer network of IPFS. As soon as you walk threw the door, you see many nodes. These nodes are just servers that are hosting some data. What you do know is you start asking around who of the servers has an idea where the `bafy...` JPEG is.

Answer (score -1):

**Ethereum** is a blockchain technology which uses **IPFS** under the hood for it's decentralised and distributed needs like global broadcast of transactions,blocks and saving those mined blocks on their respective nodes. For this type of storage needs, Ethereum uses **customised IPFS** and other protocols like **libP2P**.

Comment: Hi there. The way you've explained this is misleading. Ethereum doesn't use IPFS for any of the things you've described. IPFS is a distributed filesystem that can be used for storing files which can then be later referenced in smart contracts. IPFS isn't required to run an Ethereum node - all chain data is stored locally on the node (IPFS would be _far_ too slow... ).

Comment: Yeah I got you. I know how  IPFS works and there is project which got separated called as IPLD which is used for describing links between content-addressed data, like in Ethereum blocks.So I thought deep down ethereum uses IPFS.I might be wrong but thanks for correcting me, @RichardHorrocks.